# Rubocop: Literal used in void context.[Lint/Void]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I am having some issues correctly formatting the code below following Rubocop inspection in my Ruby on Rails Application. I keep getting the errors:

> Rubocop:Literal[:success, JSON.parse(response.to_str)] used in void context.[Lint/Void]

and

> Rubocop:Literal[:unprocessable_entity, JSON.parse(response.to_str)] used in void context.[Lint/Void].

I just can't figure out what the issue is with the code and how to fix it.

```
case response.code
when 200
  [:success, JSON.parse(response.to_str)]
  redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Logged in!'
when 422
  [:unprocessable_entity, JSON.parse(response.to_str)]
  flash.now[:alert] = 'Email or password is invalid'
  render 'new'
else
  raise "Invalid response #{response.to_str} received."
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using this `[:success, JSON.parse(response.to_str)]` and this `[:unprocessable_entity, JSON.parse(response.to_str)]` anywhere in your code. Either remove it or assign it in a variable but assigning it in a variable and not using that variable may cause the warning again.

You should remove the code which you are not using. Try this:

```
case response.code
when 200
  redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Logged in!'
when 422
  flash.now[:alert] = 'Email or password is invalid'
  render 'new'
else
  raise "Invalid response #{response.to_str} received."
end
```

or try this:

```
case response.code
when 200
  @success = [:success, JSON.parse(response.to_str)]
  redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Logged in!'
when 422
  @error = [:unprocessable_entity, JSON.parse(response.to_str)]
  flash.now[:alert] = 'Email or password is invalid'
  render 'new'
else
  raise "Invalid response #{response.to_str} received."
end
```

Let me know if it worked.